# Blocking The Tab Key

Tags: python, tkinter

I've recently made a text editor with tkinter for python.
I need a way to disable tab from being able to be used normally, so it doesn't indent.
Does anyone have any idea as to how I would achieve this?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Read up on "example, assume you wish to disable the Enter key" [Events and Bindings - Section Instance and Class Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on exactly what you did. Without more information I'm going to assume that you have a text widget somewhere and that you want to disable tab from indenting there.

Example:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Text

def no_tab(event):
    return 'break'

root = Tk()
text_widget = Text()
text_widget.pack()
text_widget.bind('<Tab>', no_tab)
root.mainloop()
```

In this example we bind the `<Tab>` key to the function `no_tab`. So everytime tab is pressed within the text widget the `no_tab` function is called. The `no_tab` function returns the magic string `'break'` which means that the action of the key won't be preformed and thus disabling the indentation that the tab key would have created otherwise.